# Trying to convert image on demand in memory and return it converted

Tags: go

I'm trying to convert an image on the fly to PNG, the source can be TIFF, jpeg, or png and I want it to always be returned as png.

Currently I'm having issues with getting the image out in a http response, so any pointers would be highly appreciated as the current error from res.write is "Cannot use 'destImage' (type error) as the type []byte"

The image processing is preferred to be done in memory rather than on file system if at all possible.

```golang
import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "crypto/tls"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/sunshineplan/imgconv"
)

var client = http.Client{}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/photo", cutterHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

func cutterHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    url := "https://proxy.local/Image.aspx?id=CAB96C9C-DA56-4BC9-8626-FC5C95FF4D95"
    http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
    reqImg, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(res, "Error %d", err)
        req.Response.StatusCode = http.StatusInternalServerError
        return
    }

    srcImage, err := imgconv.Decode(reqImg.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        req.Response.StatusCode = http.StatusInternalServerError
        return
    }

    convertedImage := imgconv.Resize(srcImage, imgconv.ResizeOption{Width: 128, Height: 128})
    var b bytes.Buffer
    buffer := bufio.NewWriter(&b)
    destImage := imgconv.Write(buffer, convertedImage, imgconv.FormatOption{Format: imgconv.PNG})
    res.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/png")
    res.Write(destImage)
}
```

Comment: please include the error message, in full, verbatim.  It's not clear whether you're paraphrasing.

Comment: @DanielFarrell I did include the full error message as said by Goland?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [ResponseWriter.Write()](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter) method accepts a slice of [bytes](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#byte) ([]byte), but you are trying to pass an [error type](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#error) (built-in interface type).

If I try to build your code I get the following error message:

> ./main.go:44:15: cannot use destImage (variable of type error) as type []byte in argument to res.Write

In the source code, I see that "destImage" variable is initialized on line 41 and has an [error type](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#error) (method [imgconv.Write()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sunshineplan/imgconv#Write) returns an error).

```
 destImage := imgconv.Write(buffer, convertedImage, imgconv.FormatOption{Format: imgconv.PNG})
```

To fix the error you need to change imgconv.Write() method call at line 41. And it can be done in the following way:

```
convertedImage := imgconv.Resize(srcImage, imgconv.ResizeOption{Width: 128, Height: 128})

res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/png")
res.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

err = imgconv.Write(res, convertedImage, imgconv.FormatOption{Format: imgconv.PNG})
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

To demonstrate, I wrote [another version](https://go.dev/play/p/7gvV7V72ayR) that you may find useful.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/sunshineplan/imgconv"
)

var client = http.Client{
    Transport: cloneTransport(),
}

func main() {
    imageURL := ImageURL("https://go.dev/blog/go-brand/Go-Logo/JPG/Go-Logo_Blue.jpg")
    http.Handle("/logos/golang.png", imageURL)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

type ImageURL string

func (imageURL ImageURL) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    if req.Method != http.MethodGet {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }

    res, err := client.Get(string(imageURL))

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("fetch %q image: %v", imageURL, err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    if res.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Printf("fetch %q image: %s [%d]", imageURL, res.Status, res.StatusCode)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err = convert(buffer, res.Body)

    defer res.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("convert %q image: %v", imageURL, err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/png")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(int64(buffer.Len()), 10))
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    if _, err = buffer.WriteTo(w); err != nil {
        log.Printf("write data: %v", err)
    }
}

func convert(w io.Writer, r io.Reader) error {
    srcImage, err := imgconv.Decode(r)

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("decode image: %w", err)
    }

    img := imgconv.Resize(srcImage, imgconv.ResizeOption{Width: 128, Height: 128})
    err = imgconv.Write(w, img, imgconv.FormatOption{Format: imgconv.PNG})

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("encode image: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}

func cloneTransport() *http.Transport {
    transport := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
    transport.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }

    return transport
}
```

Also, [another variant](https://go.dev/play/p/izKqL7oOIzl) of convert() function without CMYK support (TIFF), with using [/x/image/tiff](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/image/tiff) and [resize](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/nfnt/resize) packages.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/png"
    "io"

    _ "golang.org/x/image/tiff"
    _ "image/jpeg"

    "github.com/nfnt/resize"
)

func convert(w io.Writer, r io.Reader) error {
    img, _, err := image.Decode(r)

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("decode image: %w", err)
    }

    resizedImage := resize.Resize(128, 128, img, resize.Bicubic)
    err = png.Encode(w, resizedImage)

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("encode image: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. It works quite well for a jpg, but doesn't for a .tif file.

Example of the issue when converting: https://imgur.com/a/tvWHigx
I have no clues as to how that image is converted like that, aspect ratio just went poof or something like that?

Comment: Please provide an original image.

Comment: Original source image is available here: https://files.samip.fi/AG.tif for a week.

Comment: Perhaps this problem is related to the color space. I get the correct result if I first change the color space from CMYK to RGB using ImageMagick.

Comment: Do you happen to know if imgconv can be used for changing the color space to RGB?

Comment: [imgconv.Decode()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sunshineplan/imgconv#Decode) [use](https://github.com/sunshineplan/imgconv/blob/main/convert.go#L9) [github.com/sunshineplan/tiff](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sunshineplan/tiff) for TIFF format and this package has [CMYK support](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sunshineplan/tiff#readme-goal). But in your case the result is incorrect.